# Is these Trees isomorphic or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Is these Trees isomorphic or not?

They have **same** structure but they have **different code**. Because one of them is **minimum** code.

[image]

*Thank you for your answers in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret the lemma and the definitions correctly, it seems that there are two definitions at work here:

> The *code* of an ordered rooted tree works through the branches "from left to right", i.e., following the order.
>
> The *minimum code* of an ordered rooted tree works through the branches on a "smallest binary number first" basis.

While the *code* of an ordered rooted tree respects the ordering, the *minimum code* may not (changing the ordering of the branches will give the same minimum code).

Therefore, we are led to the conclusion that the *minimum code* is **not a code**. This nomenclature is confusing, and this should've been emphasized in the document somewhere. Or, what would've been better, different terms ought to have been used.

---

Bottom line: The *code* of a tree **exclusively** refers to the bottom-up, left-to-right encoding displayed in the left picture. With this more restrictive definition of *code*, it is not too hard to see that the lemma does indeed hold.